# Habilitar campo ao selecionar "Tipo"

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte campo:

```
    <div class="line">
        <label class="control-label">Tipo</label>
        <select class="input-xxlarge idTipo" name="idTipo" id="idTipo" onChange="getParametro()" style="width: 715px !important;">
        <option value="">Selecione o Tipo</option>
        <option value="819">Faltas</option>
        <option value="60">Atrasos</option>
        <option value="69">Saída Antecipada</option>
        </select>
    </div>

<div class="line">
    <label class="control-label">Data Solicitado</label>
    <input id="dp1" class="input-small" style="width: 135px" name="data" type="date" required="required">

    <label class="control-label">Data Cadastro</label>
    <input id="dp1" class="input-small" style="width: 135px" name="data" type="date" required="required">

    <label class="control-label" style="width: 58px !important">Horários</label>
    <input id="dp1" class="input-small" name="hora_inicio" type="time" disabled>
    <input id="dp1" class="input-small" name="hora_final" type="time" disabled>
</div>
```

Gostaria que ao selecionar o idTipo, e se for idTipo = 60, habilitasse então os campos de horários que temos mais abaixo... Como fazer isso em Jquery?

Este jQuery faz a busca do próximo campo (que não coloquei no código ai), mas podemos integrar nesse jQuery para habilitar o horário.

```
    function getParametro() {
        var id = $('#idTipo').val();
        $(".idParametro").append('<option value="0">Carregando...</option>');
        $.post("<? echo base_url(''); ?>faltas/ajax/parametro/" + id,
            {idParametro:jQuery(id).val()},
            function(valor){
                 $(".idParametro").html(valor);
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes ter um oscultador de eventos no jQuery que detete se o select mudou e para o valor `60`. Aí coloca ou retira o `disabled`.

Seria algo assim:

```
var inputs = $('input[name="hora_inicio"], input[name="hora_final"]');
$('#idTipo').on('change', function(){
    if (this.value == '60') inputs.removeAttr('disabled');
    else inputs.attr('disabled', 'true');
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctr0wj6r/